# Converting an object in an array of objects into an array, while preserving other data

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following array of objects:

```
const datasubject = 
[
 0: {
    level: "standard 3"
    subject: "English"
    _id: xxx
    coreCompetencies {
       0gHq0U5E667L4EdGbdZ2h: "Grammar",
       9CfalSpzKYIV7AaWKBUwg: "Listening",
       9boIfWUEGdj3WGxJL12XB: "Reading",
       QZ11uYQ8CXkRk0LWenjqj: "Writing",
       ZG1gtxRg6quIOYaTr6CUy: "Speaking"
    }
 },
 1: {...},
 2: {...}
]
```

I would like to change the `coreCompetencies` into an array of values e.g. `["Grammar", "Listening", "Reading", "Writing", "Speaking"]` while preserving the other data. I've tried `.map` but got confused as it only returns the `coreCompetencies` object, without the other details. This is what I did that returned only the `coreCompetencies` object:

```
const datacore = datasubject.map(value => value.coreCompetencies);
```

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
const datasubject = 
[
 0: {
    level: "standard 3"
    subject: "English"
    _id: xxx
    coreCompetencies ["Grammar","Listening","Reading","Writing","Speaking"]
 },
 1: {...},
 2: {...}
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const datacore = datasubject.map(({coreCompetencies, ...rest})=> {
  return {...rest, coreCompetencies: Object.values(coreCompetencies)}
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much @tam-dc! This works, and I'm using your solution because I can see where the 'rest' are.

Comment: A better implementation :)

Answer (score 2):

You should do something like this :

```
const datacore = datasubject.map(value => {
  value.coreCompetencies = Object.values(value.coreCompetencies);
  return value;
})
```

Comment: Thanks @binariedme ! i've also tried your solution and it works! Super awesome!